# Возможно ли зарегестрировать команду в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, handlers

Всем привет, писал долгое время телеграмм ботов, в основном на aiogram, и решил попробовать себя в разработке дискорд ботов, и я сразу столкнулся с таким вопросом, на который я не нашел ответ на просторах интернета: Могу ли я зарегестрировать хендлер в discord.py?
Аналог в aiogram: "dp.register_message_handler"

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться с [**руководством**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-discord-py). Тут подробно описаны примеры создания обработчиков сообщений, команд и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]